# Setting up Snowflake with Terraform: unable to scan row for SHOW DATABASES

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am following a [tutorial](https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/terraforming_snowflake/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) and I am trying to create a database on Snowflake using Terraform.

Some (important) points:

- It's an organization account
- As cloud uses Azure
- It's on West Europe

The steps I had done until now:

1. Create an RSA key for authentication
2. Create the user tf-snow in snowflake + granting it roles
3. Found out the region and account locator
4. Create the environment file and sourced it

Now I am trying to run:

```
terraform apply -var-file vars/staging.tfvars -target module.snowflake.snowflake_database.db
```

and I get the following error:

`Error: unable to scan row for SHOW DATABASES: Post "https://<account_locator>.<azure-region>.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=<request_id>&request_guid=<request_guid>=SYSADMIN": x509: certificate is valid for *.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com, *.us-west-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com, *.global.snowflakecomputing.com, *.snowflakecomputing.com, *.prod1.us-west-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com, *.prod2.us-west-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com, not <account_locator>.<azure-region>.snowflakecomputing.com`

Any pointer on how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the terraform code you are using to the question?

Comment: It looks to me based on the error message that you're failing [OCSP check](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ocsp.html). Do you have like a proxy in between that filters Snowflake hostnames?

Comment: @Sergiu I don't have anything special set up. Only the env file, the main tf file and the snowflake module. Anything about a proxy rings a bell to me

Comment: @Sergiu From what I can see, in the web browser I have the certificate from *.west-europe.azure.snowflakecomputing.com but it's not present in the error message...

Comment: The proxy is something in your network (might be as well company network), not part of something you setup. Are you using a company computer and do you know if your company is using a proxy ? You can use [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) to see if you have issues with OCSP.

Comment: This could be an issue with the snowflake provider as I ran into this issue recently and it was resolved when I did an upgrade to the terraform snowflake provider with a `terraform init -upgrade`